# What's solution to make task background in iOS same service in Android?

Tags: ios, mobile, cordova

I'm newbie iOS. I have been develop Phonegap for Android and iOS. My App is update data from server every 1hour. In Android, i use service to do that. My app in Android working very good. Now, i want to develop version for iOS, and i have problem when update data from server every 1hour. I was research but not find anyway for my app.I don't know what's solution to replace for service in Android. Can you help me, what's solution. This have been kill me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is NO as Apple has restriction on background task running especially cases like yours.

But if you are downloading small amount of content, you do have some other options. From IOS 4.0 or above, you can declare your app to run in background when you fall under the following categories:

Audio
Location updates
Voice over IP
Newsstand downloads
External accessory communication
Bluetooth networking
Bluetooth data sharing
Background fetch (IOS 7) 
Remote notifications (IOS 7)

In order to do so, you need to flag your app in the info.plist for Required Background Modes option. Apple will review your app specific in this area once you declared the option.

For your case to download the data, the possible option is to use the new feature in IOS 7 that's the background fetch or remote notification above. The suggestion from DOM was not asking you to download the content through push notification. But instead to use push notification to wake up your application and start downloading new content.

If you don't want to use push notification, the only way to go is register for background fetch. However, no matter which option you want to use, each download will only last for 30 seconds. And after that, your app will put into suspension mode again.

you can have a look on the link here:

[Declaring Your App’s Supported Background Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW23)

Comment: Thanks for replace. I have been deploy a server for push notification. Background fetch (IOS 7) is good solution, but newest, not many user update and used now. It will solution i choose after more duration.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to use the push services instead of having your app go get data. Making your app do it is unreliable with phonegap apps because you cant create a service interface and you can not guarantee that your app will be running. With push service though, if your app isn't running, it will be woken up in a manner of speaking.

Take a look at [this](http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/) great how-to article that also discusses what push provides you.

Comment: Thank you for answer. My server is performing (for many app in web and destop) and very large. If use push notification, i must have server(i don't want to do that) to interact and sent notification to user's device. It seem somewhat complex. But i will try again.