# BackgroundFetch / Background running app using PhoneGap Build

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cordova

OK I have done a lot of research over the last few days, reading a lot of posts on here. I have build an app that using the accelerometer and geo-location.

Now thanks in part to many different posts on here and other sites I have got most of my app working without any problems.

I now have to get it working as a background app. I am building this for iOS and android, but the main aim is iOS. I know that iOS7 changed a few things but also add support for BackgroundFetch, how do I use that within a app that I will be building with build.phonegap.com?

Now I have found this plugin, de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background-mode but when I added it to the config.xml file, phonegap build says its unsupported?

I know there is a list of areas, [What's solution to make task background in iOS same service in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956807/whats-solution-to-make-task-background-in-ios-same-service-in-android) , where you can list in your 'plist file' for iOS and state what type of application it is and iOS will run it in the background because its using one of these features.

Now I have read somewhere - not to sure where - that the config.xml is built, when phonegap build runs into the plist file, so somewhere in that file I should be able to state that it is application using this and that, therefore run in the background?

So is there any many of making my app run in the background?

Any help would be most welcome

Thanks

Glenn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resources you have found are referring to building apps locally on your machine, not with phonegap build. You will not be able to achieve the functionality you are looking for with PGBuild as they don't allow that level of configuration.

To achieve this you will need to setup a local cordova/phonegap client and build your app from your computer.

Comment: That is what I was thinking, because the list of 'supported' apps in there plugins list was very limited, some of which are very cool (socialsharing, very easy to use, very cool). But I am running on a PC, I do have a LAMP stack set up on a Ubuntu VM, which I have Node.JS & Grunt.js installed on. But the SDK support for iOS builds is only (as far as I know) only available in xcode on a mac? or can I install it on my LAMP stack somehow?

Comment: Any way what about the config.xml is there any way of telling that app that I am using geo-location and I need it to background update?

Comment: Unfortunately it's very difficult to build for iOS with a system that can't run xcode. You could try formatting the plugin that you need, to the spec for use on PGBuild and then submit it to them as a third-party plugin. I tried this, and almost a month later it's still pending review. As for the config, no you cannot at this time. Maybe in future version of PG

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I would not be able to submit an app anyway, I see if I can get it to work in another way.